# How to create and maintain mongodb atlas datalake programmatically?

Tags: mongodb, data-lake, atlas-data-lake

I want to create and maintain mongodb atlas datalake programmatically but seems there is no option available. I could find out one API which can be used to create/update/delete data lake but that it only allows to set some options. Here is the link I am following - https://docs.mongodb.com/datalake/reference/api/dataLakes-create-one-tenant/#request-body-parameters

Doesn anyone know how to setup other options like data store, storage etc which you can do from mongodb atlas UI?